# Meaning of "I'm harder to forget than I was to leave."

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality, comparative-constructions

In Taylor Swift's *I bet you think about me*, a lyrical line says

> I'm harder to forget than I was to leave.

I've been thinking about the meaning for a while and come up with the following explanation:

It means both "forgetting me" and "leaving me" are hard but the former is even harder. The usage of present tense in "I'm harder to forget" is to express this is ever-present.

Does it make sense? Also, do native speakers use this structure to describe things like that usually? I barely see similar structure in other contexts though, so I am not even sure it is grammatically correct. Any comment and help will be absolutely appreciated!!

Comment: Never assume that a song lyric or a line of a poem is a common construction or even grammatically correct. You should not try to learn proper English grammar from songs. That said, I agree with your interpretation of the meaning.

Comment: No, native speakers don't use this structure usually -- we'd write it like "I'm harder to forget than I am to leave." But yes, you got the jist of it. Taylor Swift is not known for her intelligence, so don't assume too much from her piffle.

Comment: "I'm harder (now, in the present) to forget than I was (then, in the past) to leave" seems entirely appropriate use of tenses.

Comment: He thought he could leave her without feeling any pain, but now, for him, her memory persists.

Comment: Comparisons using two different tenses are very common in English: This **is** more difficult for me to say than it **was** to write.

Comment: It is easier for me to make love to a beautiful woman now than it will be when I'm aged 90.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey That sentence is quite funny lol!! Thanks for providing one more example

Comment: @FeliniusRex - "In the fall of 2018, Swift finally comes out of the closet politically to intervene on behalf of Democrats in a midterm election in her home state of Tennessee. As the Washington Post put it, this announcement “fell like a hammer across the Trump-worshipping subforums of the far-right Internet, where people had convinced themselves… that the world-famous pop star was a secret MAGA fan.” Donald Trump goes on camera to smirk that he now likes Swift’s music a little less. The singer is successful in enlisting tens of thousands of young people to register to vote. Sounds OK to me.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - in fact, more than OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparison using two different verb tenses:

Let's put this in the third person and the second clause in the past tense, because it is easier to "see/hear":

- She **is** harder to forget than she **was** to leave.
  Meaning: It is harder to forget her (now) than it was to leave her (then).

Another example:

- They **are** harder to play with than they **were** to fight with.
  Meaning: It is harder to play with them (now) than it was to fight with (them then).

Now, back to Taylor Swift:

I'm harder to forget than I was to leave.

The comparison can be tricky as it **mixes two verb tenses**, which is fine but can sound off when it isn't.

Meaning: I'm harder to forget [now] than I was to leave [then].

Mixing verb tenses in a comparison of actions like this is fine, if it works.

Other examples with other tenses:

- It's been easier jogging in the morning than it was playing tennis in the evening.
- They'll be easier to deal with now than they were last week.

Comment: Cross-posted with me. Perfect.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey So, amigo, when didya become woke? Was it that dog thing? :)

Comment: Somebody, a well established member,  responded angrily to a comment of mine and said they had no time for "woke nonsense" from "social justice warriors". Right wing code for "commie perverts". Funny how you can go off people. I decided that as I am glad to be thought progressive and in favour of decency, to own the epithet.

Comment: Straight away started getting downvotes :-)

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey I'm widya. :) Woke me too. Ha ha. Think I saw that comment and it just seemed completely over the top to me. Cheers, luv. Some of 'em ain't got no sense of humour, innit?

Comment: "Let's put...the second clause in the past tense" -- how are you "putting" it when it was *already* in the past tense in the original quote? I would say "*keep* the second clause in the past tense".

Comment: @nanoman - Lambie was creating a new example sentence. 'Let's put' is appropriate.

Comment: Hey Michael, I wanted to create a chat room, but now I see that only mods can do that, I think.

Comment: Maybe we should stand for election? :-)

Comment: I think I'm gonna ask Colleen to create a private room for us. I mistakenly thought that a certain number of pts, entitled one to create a room. I wish getting info. on SE about the how the site works were easier.